# Separate a certain piece of data from html with given start and endpoints

Tags: c#, html

I am learning screen-scraping using C# and I was wondering

**How can** I separate certain pieces of gathered html,
I am using htmlAgilityPack and ScrapySharp library's for scraping thus with this code I can retrieve a html page:

```
WebPage PageResult = Browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri("localhost"));
Console.WriteLine(PageResult);
```

Of course I get back the whole source code with all the syntax and mishmash, **but what If** I wanted to only catch data between `<h2></h2>` tags and omit all else?

My very simple-minded pseudo code would be:

```
If result reads h2
Trim all behind
start writing out after 
If result reads /h2
stop writing
Trim anything that comes after
```

**The main question I'm having** is how do I `feed` In the rule that when I read `h2` trim everything from before, write the data after that and if `/h2` appears, stop and trim the end of the result?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can achieve this, one such would be to red the page as XML and parse the data you are looking for,

This can be with the use of,
XElement
XmlElement
XDocument
etc.

The second way, would be to use a third-party library like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/), this also supports XPath as well,

> var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form//input");